# Google Chat like Div

Tags: html, css

Anyone know how to create a division like the the ones used in Google Chat inside Google Mail? i.e. they are always at the bottom.

I hope there is a way to create it with HTML and CSS only.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm 99% sure that you can't align things to the bottom of a browser window without JavaScript.  I'd be very interested in how to do it if it is indeed possible, since it would simplify some stuff in my company's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple CSS - `position: fixed; bottom: 0px;` should work in all modern browsers - and IE6 when using [IE7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)